# A linear transformation that multiplies a column of a matrix by a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

As far as I know, In order to multiply the $i$th row of a square matrix A by a scalar $\lambda$ we can multiply it with a square diagonal matrix M whose diagonal entries are 1 except $a_{ii} = \lambda$ :

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & \lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1 n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2 n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n 1} & a_{n 2} & \cdots & a_{n n}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1 n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2 n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\lambda a_{i1} & \lambda a_{i2} & \cdots & \lambda a_{in} \\
a_{n 1} & a_{n 2} & \cdots & a_{n n}
\end{array}\right)
$$

My question is, how can I find a Matrix M, such as when I multiply it with Matrix A, the jth column of A gets multiplied by $\lambda$?

Thank you

Comment: If you multiply AM instead of MA it happens naturally, but I don't think there is any general answer to your question.

Comment: @Peter This **is** the general answer. It amounts to working on the transpose: transpose $A$, left-multiply by $M$ to affect the $j$th row, transpose again.

Answer (score 1):

No matrix $M$ exists that for any matrix $A$, $MA$ results in only the $j$th columns being scaled by $\lambda$. Suppose $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are the columns of $A$. Then we have that

$$MA = [MA_1\ \ldots \ MA_n].$$

If we then had that $A_i = A_j$ for $i \neq j$, then if $M$ existed, it would have to scale $A_i$ as well.

---

Your confusion seems to stem from the fact that the map

$$[A_1 \ \ldots A_n] \mapsto [A_1 \ \ldots\ \lambda A_j \ \ldots \ A_n].$$

is a linear map. Hence must be representable as a matrix. But to do, we must think of $A$ as a vector instead of a matrix. So we have $\hat{A} = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 \\ \vdots \\ A_n\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. Then $M$ would be an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix.

Comment: I think I understand everything you said except this one: "If we then had that $A_i=A_j$ for i≠j, then if $M$ existed, it would have to scale $A_i$ as well."

Comment: How can we find this $n^2 \times n^2$ marix?

Comment: Suppose $M$ existed such that for all $A$, $MA = M[A_1\ \ldots \ A_n] = [MA_1\ \ldots M\ A_n]= [A_1 \ \ldots \lambda A_j \ \ldots A_n]$. Since $M$ acts on the columns of $A$ independently from each other. If two columns are equal, $M$ has to do the same thing to both of the columns. 

Well you already know how to create a matrix that scales certain rows, how could you use that to create the matrix that you need?

Comment: Correct, but I wonder if this is really what the OP is asking for. If the question is "is this possible by left-multiplying", right. But if it's "how do I do it in practice", then right-multiply.